# Macro to place "" in formula

Tags: excel, vlookup, vba

I am trying to create a macro that will replace the formula in a vlookup cell to include a if(isna... parameter, replacing =vlookup(a1,b1:c2:,2,false) with 
=if(isna(vlookup(a1,b1:c2:,2,false)),"",vlookup(a1,b1:c2:,2,false)).

The problem i am running into is having the macro place the "" component, as the macro interprets "" as nothing (just like it would interpret "X" as X and not "X"). I tried making it null and false etc. but that places a 0 in the cell, which does not work for a list of text. Any ideas? My macro is below:

```
Sub vlookuperror()
Dim Orig_formula As String
Dim new_formula
Dim noequal
dim quote

quote=""
Orig_formula = ActiveCell.Formula
noequal = Mid(Orig_formula, 2)
new_formula = "=if(isna(" & noequal & ")," & quote & "," & noequal & ")"
ActiveCell.Formula = new_formula

End Sub
```

Comment: Use `quote=Chr$(34)` instead of "". 34 is the ASCII code for **"**

Comment: worked perfectly, just had to do that twice to get double quotes - thanks!

Comment: I didn't get you needed it twice... ;) anyway, yes: `quote = Chr$(34) & Chr$(34)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub vlookuperror()
Dim Orig_formula As String
Dim new_formula
Dim noequal
dim quote

quote=""""""
Orig_formula = ActiveCell.Formula
noequal = Mid(Orig_formula, 2)
new_formula = "=if(isna(" & noequal & ")," & quote & "," & noequal & ")"
ActiveCell.Formula = new_formula

End Sub
```

Or you should be able to concatenate two Chr$(34) together - and replace that - see Frank N. Stein's suggestion in comment above. - a la: quote = Chr$(34) & Chr$(34)